# Group Assignment Java text book

Tags: java, string

I've been doing this program for about 30 minutes now, and I want to make it in this certain format even though I'm pretty sure there are better methods of doing this program!

What I've been trying to do is from alphabet A to I should be placed in group in terms of there first letter of their last name. And, J to S should be group 2 and T to Z should be group 3. I'm not sure how I can make the output equal to group1 and any other groups depending on there last name of course!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GroupAssignment {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        String output;
        String group1 = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i";
        String group2 = "j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s";
        String group3 = "t,u,v,w,x,y,z";
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter your first name: ");
        firstName = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter your last name: ");
        lastName = input.nextLine();

        output = lastName.substring(0,1).toLowerCase();

        if (output.equals(group1)) {
            System.out.println(firstName+ lastName+ "is assigned to Group 1.");
        }
        else if (output.equals(group2)) {
            System.out.println(firstName+ lastName+ "is assigned to Group 2.");
        }
        else if (output.equals(group3)) {
            System.out.println(firstName+ lastName+ "is assigned to Group 3.");
        }

    }

}
```

Please help me how I can make this work!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "make this work". What is it's purpose, what does it do right and what does it do wrong? You've spent 30 minutes trying to get it to work so tell us *what* you did during those 30 minutes so we don't waste time doing the same things.

Comment: What I've been trying to do is from alphabet A to I should be placed in group in terms of there first letter of their last name. And, J to S should be group 2 and T to Z should be group 3. I'm not sure how I can make the output equal to group1 and any other groups depending on there last name of course!

Comment: @Skypanties Edit your question instead of leaving important information in comments.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `.equals`: after all the first letter of the lastname cannot be `a,b,c,d,...`. It can be only one of these. You can use [`.contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) however:

```
if (group1.contains(output)) {
    System.out.println(firstName+ lastName+ "is assigned to Group 1.");
} else if (group2.contains(output)) {
    System.out.println(firstName+ lastName+ "is assigned to Group 2.");
} else if (group3.contains(output)) {
    System.out.println(firstName+ lastName+ "is assigned to Group 3.");
}
```

[**jdoodle demo**](http://jdoodle.com/a/o0)

Another problem is that your print:

```
System.out.println(firstName+ lastName+...
```

I don't know about all cultures, but many add a space between the `firstName` and the `lastName` so:

```
System.out.println(firstName+" "+lastName+...
```

Is probably a better option.

Note however that this is not the right way to do it. A string is not a *collection*, it is a sequence. There are faster ways to check if a collection contains an element. I'm thinking about a `HashSet<Char>` or `TreeSet<Char>` which can do lookups in average-case constant time or logarithmic time.

Comment: Man, I appreciate this a lot you've just set me up perfectly for a test tomorrow for strings unit! Thank you so much I greatly appreciate it! =)
Also, that is correct I'm 100% sure that there are better ways doing it but, this is something my teacher requires our class to do, since we've just started java a (started in 2015, early February) so we've been only up to strings unit up until now.